# MySQL slave is continuously lagging behind master

Tags: mysql, replication

I was given two fairly new servers and setup master and slave running MySQL 5.7.17, Linux RedHat 6. Both servers are using binlog_format=STATEMENT.

I can't understand why my slave is processing so slowly though I know the bottleneck with the single thread process from my slave. I believe our master server does not contain a lot of parallel queries though.

Slave > show processlist;

`Id: 22593
   User: system user
   Host:
     db: Database1
Command: Connect
   Time: 2364340
  State: updating
   Info: update TableA set colA.....`

This transaction is processing like 0.5s for every update. The total rows count for the table is just under 100,000 rows. I am not sure if my expectation is right that it should be fast.
I turn on general_log to capture for several seconds and switch off back. 
Excerpt:
`2016-12-28T10:26:53.937824Z     22093 Query     COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */
2016-12-28T10:26:53.938293Z     22093 Query     BEGIN
2016-12-28T10:26:54.404481Z     22093 Query     update Table10 set  COLA='XXX', COLB='XXXX', COLC='', COLD='', COLE='XXXX', COLF='XXXX' where COLB='YY' and COLF='ZZZZZZ'
2016-12-28T10:26:54.404576Z     22093 Query     COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */`

`slave > show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: masterA
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: masterA-bin.000117
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 818913948
               Relay_Log_File: slaveB-relay-bin.001168
                Relay_Log_Pos: 42738489
        Relay_Master_Log_File: masterA-bin.000116
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 42738264
              Relay_Log_Space: 1939474024
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 60598
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 10
                  Master_UUID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: updating
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

`masterA> show master status\G;`
`*************************** 1. row ***************************`
`File: masterA-bin.000117`
`Position: 818913948`
`Binlog_Do_DB:`
`Binlog_Ignore_DB:`
`Executed_Gtid_Set:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Based on the readings, my I/O thread is doing not too bad. Catching up with master log at masterA-bin.000117. But the SQL thread is lagging behind. `masterA-bin.000116`. `Relay_Log_Pos: 42738489`

SQL thread is replaying at `slaveB-relay-bin.001168`. But when I check my OS directory /log, I can see slaveB-relay-bin.001341 as the latest generated.

The slave is continuously lagging behind master. I have set

1. sync_binlog=1
2. Comment log-slave-updates
3. innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

But it helps a little only, reducing probably 1-2 seconds of lag.

I am using STATEMENT binlog, will it matters if some tables does not have primary/unique key?

I'd to know if there are other means to speed up the replication without multithreaded slave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to speed up the queries.

`Table10` needs a composite `INDEX(COLB, COLF)` (in either order).  If it already has that, then let's see some more of the 'slow' queries.

On the slave, turn on `log_slow_slave_statements`, lower `long_quer_time` to `0.5`, turn on the slowlog, preferably to a `FILE`.  Wait a day, then use `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog.  Then let's discuss the first few.

Comment: Turn on that the indexes on the table were missing. Recreated the index and speed are much more faster.

Comment: Recreating an index will not speed up things in MySQL.  (Recreating _may_ shrink the disk footprint some.)